# Trouble comparing Gromov's presentation of the classical isoperimetric inequality with wikipedia's

Tags: geometry

In the first page of Gromov's article [PAUL LEVY'S ISOPERIMETRIC INEQUALITY](http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/11[33].pdf) one reads:

[image]

However in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality), one reads

> In mathematics, the **isoperimetric inequality** is a geometric ineqaulity involving the surface area of a set and its volume. In $n$-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^n$ the inequality lower bounds the surface area $\operatorname{surf}(S)$ of a set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ by its volume $\operatorname{vol}(S)$. $$\operatorname{surf}(S)\geq n\operatorname{vol}(S)^{\tfrac{n-1}{n}}\operatorname{vol}(B_1)^{\tfrac{1}{n}},$$ where $B_1\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a unit ball. The equality holds when $S$ is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am having trouble seeing that these two definitions agree.

Let's examine first Gromov's presentation:

First question is: What is the point of working on the standard $n+1$-dimensional sphere? 
$$\Bbb{S}^{n+1}\{x\in \Bbb{R^{n+1}}\colon x_1^2 + \ldots + x^2_{n+2} = 1\}$$
is an $n+1$ dimensional space.

Why not work on $\Bbb{R}^{n+1}$
If we multiply both sides of Gromov's classical inequality by the volume of $\Bbb{S}^{n+1}$ we arrive at:

$$\operatorname{Vol}(\partial V_0) > \operatorname{vol}(\partial B_\alpha) $$ where $B_\alpha$ is the ball in $\Bbb{S}^{n+1}$ with volume $\operatorname{Vol}(V_0)$.

Translating into words: the surface of the smooth domain $V_0$ is bigger than the surface of the  ball ($B_\alpha$) with the same volume as $V_0$.

One could put this into fractions by saying:

$$\frac{\operatorname{Vol}( \partial V_0)}{\operatorname{Vol} (V_0)} \geq \frac{\operatorname{Vol}( \partial B_\alpha)}{\operatorname{Vol} (B_\alpha)} $$

Why does Gromov divide by the volume of $\Bbb{S}^{n+1}$?

When it comes to wikipedia we find

$$\frac{\operatorname{Vol}(\partial S)}{\operatorname{Vol}(S)} \geq n \bigg(\frac{\operatorname{vol}(B1)}{\operatorname{vol} (S)}\bigg)^{1/n} $$

How do these two coincide?

Comment: You should read the Wikipedia article further. The introductory paragraph deals only with the IP inequality in $R^n$, but further down it treats more general spaces such as spheres. When working with the sphere **you are not working with $R^{n+1}$**, since in $R^{n+1}$ there are more ways to fill in a surface of dimension $n-1$ lying on the round sphere.